# Display post for a week

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Can someone help me how to display the post only for a week? i have this code that works fine in post_date:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => '1 week ago'
      )
    )
  ); 
?>
<ul class="weekly-list">
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

but how to do it in the custom field date. Because my other events is posted a week before the events. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This Might help you to get solution:

```
 $week = date('W');
 $year = date('Y');
 $the_query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> "><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: how i will insert the c_date custom fields for the events?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer was along the good track. Just modify your `date_query`:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date( 'Y' ),
            'week' => date( 'W' ),
        ),
    ),
  );
?>
<ul class="weekly-list">
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: how i will insert the c_date custom fields for the events in the date_query?

Comment: Is this correct? $customDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'c_date', true); 'year' => date( 'Y', strtotime($customDate)),
                    'week' => date( 'W', strtotime($customDate) ),

Comment: But you'll get post meta only inside the loop, how can you get the post ID so that you can use in the arguments for the query?
Also I don't know what exactly are you hoping to achieve with this? The above query will show posts only from the last week, and that's it.

Comment: i am trying to query the post of the week but what i am confuse if the post that i posted 1 week before the events. So i made a custom date "c_date" for this. Example the event is for March first week. So for now it will not display only for this week and then if march is approaching it will display.

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182767/most-popular-post-for-last-7-days) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140516/why-does-inclusive-not-work-in-this-wordpress-loop) posts. Especially the second one, it talks about inclusive dates...

Comment: i did not get any information on  how i will insert the custom field date i created.

Comment: Try adding `'meta_key' => 'c_date', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` in your query.

Comment: this date_query is basing the post_date right? how can we change it to base the custom date field?

Comment: For that you'll need [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) look at

Comment: if i use meta_query does this solve my proble to display the post weekly through the custom post date i made?

Comment: Well how can I know that? I don't have your data :D Try it out and see if it works ;)

Comment: Not working. It's basing on the default post_date. I tried to set the custom date Feb 12, feb 13 for each post. It display. But when i tried to put feb 20. It display also on the event of this week.